# Warning : filesize function failing to operate

Tags: php, warnings, filesize, if-statement

The Following Code:

```
<?php
$filevar = "/images/staunton/{$options_item['base_var']}.gif";

if(filesize($filevar) > 1616){
    $setstatus = "enabled";
}
else{
    $setstatus = "disabled";
}       
?>
```

Results in:

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for /images/staunton/3-25.gif in [Originating PHPFILE(Edited)] on line 24
```

The Path is the correct file.... my hosting server is running php 5.2 - is this a synax error? I've been looking at similar code and it seems to look correct.

Comment: Does the file in `$filevar` exist? Does the PHP process have the rights to read it, and the directory it's in?

Comment: I don't think your server has a *root-level* folder named `images`.

Comment: Check your (apache?) server has read access to the file and that the full path is correct.

Comment: @DCoder I think you're probably right - @OP Do a `file_exists()` on `$filevar` and see what happens

Comment: The path is *not* the correct file... are you confusing URLs and *local file paths*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$filevar = "/images/staunton/{$options_item['base_var']}.gif";
```

you probably want:

```
$filevar = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/images/staunton/{$options_item['base_var']}.gif";
```

because you probably was confusing the relative path of your image inside the **document root** of your page vs the **absolute path** of the image in the filesystem.

Try it and comment back.

Comment: Also, make sure that the folder (which the file belongs) is not writable.

Comment: Great answer, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] was also the solution to my problem.