# Cannot read large file using XmlStreamer

Tags: php, xml

I using `xmlStreamer` to read xml but not able to read the whole xml. This function return only two rows ? How can I get the whole data of xml?

```
<?php
class SimpleXmlStreamer extends XmlStreamer
{
    public function processNode($xmlString, $elementName, $nodeIndex)
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
        $something = (string)$xml->Something->SomethingElse->ReadThis;
        echo "$nodeIndex: Extracted string '$something' from parent node '$elementName'\n";     
        return true;
    }
}

$streamer = new SimpleXmlStreamer("myLargeXmlFile.xml");
if ($streamer->parse()) {
    echo "Finished successfully";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't find root node";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue of memory only. I have use XMLReader class to read xml data and easily get the data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears when parsing remote XMLs. You probably are getting this warning: 
"Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for ***yourfile***.xml in ***path***\XmlStreamer.php on line 32". If this is the case, you can replace at line 32 in XmlStreamer.php the line:

```
$this->totalBytes = filesize($mixed);
```

with these 2 lines:

```
$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($mixed, TRUE));
$this->totalBytes = $head['content-length'][1];
```

The solution for getting the file size of a remote file is from here: [Warning : filesize function failing to operate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498895/warning-filesize-function-failing-to-operate)

After this, depending on the file size, you might have problems with memory_limit, but you'll probably be fine.

**Note:** I'm not sure why `$head['content-length'][1]` has to be multiplied as it is in bytes. Otherwise the full file is not parsed. Maybe someone else can clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because you are trying to use more memory then defined in the php.
try to expand your php memory usage only in this specific code.

But first try your code on a small xml and check if your code is actually working.

Comment: I have tried with small xml also but geting only one row after that it reaches echo Finished successfully.

Comment: If I am increasing the memory I am able to read some more rows. I have increases upto 1 gb and am able to read 15 rows. Please let me know if there is any solution with increasing memory size.