# Getting error when i am sending attachment mail Warning: filesize()

Tags: php

Error:

> Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ddlg.jpg in /home4/moses/public_html/website.com/ipn-page-template .php on line 72

My Code:

```
$path = 'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/';
    $filename = 'unnamed.jpg';
    $mailto = 'email@domain.com';
    $subject = "Thank you for Than Near";

    $file = $path . $filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498895/warning-filesize-function-failing-to-operate

Comment: $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) *can* allow checking the size of remote items via fopen wrappers if given a URL (as you're doing), but like many such things it's not reliable. Make sure fopen wrappers are enabled, and that you can reach the item first before trying to use it.

If you're doing this during a page load, you're also asking for it to hang if the remote host does not respond, so you should really pre-fetch images and serve them from a local file store.

Writing your own email code is never a good idea; [Use a library](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: it's solved error was that:- $path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/";           Thank you every one

Comment: OK, so "Serve them from a local file store" was correct, and your error was in using a remote URL as the path.